# why require_once it's not working If I called same file from different folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my root directory

```
dev (root folder)     
|   zones(folder)
|   |    index.php
|   |    new-zone.php
|   |    update-zone.php
index.php
login.php
signup.php
header.php
functions.php
```

outside of root folder I have  config file called `config.php`

Now from `header.php` page I am calling following code and it's working fine:

```
require_once('../config/config.php');
require_once('functions.php');
```

But now I need to call same `header.php` file from the folder `zones/index.php` page and it's code is bellow :

```
require_once("../header.php");
```

But showing following error message :

> require_once(../config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in D:\Softwares
>   Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev\header.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../config/config.php' (include_path='.;D:\Softwares
>   Installed\xampp-old\php\PEAR\;D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\libs\') in
>   D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev\header.php on line
>   3

How can I solve this error ? I want to call `header.php` file from different **folders** ?

**Note :** I am using following `.htaccess` rules to use SEO friendly url and custom error message page.

**.htaccess code :**

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/aponit/dev/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/aponit/dev/404.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:zones/)?update-zone/(\w+)/?$ update-zone.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: the answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
__DIR__
```

Infront of the import inside header.php file.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config/config.php');
```

See [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Showing error message : `Warning: require_once(D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev../config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev\header.php on line 3`

Comment: `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev../config/config.php' (include_path='.;D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\php\PEAR\;D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\libs\') in D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev\header.php on line 3`

Comment: Put / there as well, modified my answer.

Comment: well it's working fine. Now I `echo` the code and it's output is : `D:\Softwares Installed\xampp-old\htdocs\aponit\dev/../config/config.php`

Comment: My question is there is a dot `/../` ! then how it's finding the `config.php` file ?

Comment: I don't get what you meant. If you mean /../, that just tells PHP to go back one folder. If you mean inside the require_once, the . puts the 2 strings (_ _DIR_ _ and '/../config/config.php') togheter.

Comment: Great Answer! But I found a not-found error message when click on this link from index.php page from zones folder : `<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."zones/update-zone/$zone_id"?>" >Edit</a>`. Should I need to edit my .httaccess rules ?

Comment: Check that the SITE_URL is right and has a trailing slash in the end. I think it might not have a trailing slash. Try using echo SITE_URL . "/zones/update-zone" .. etc